# getActivity causes the App to crash when called from a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-listfragment, android-lifecycle

I am trying to test the screent orientation of the device when using `fragment` to learn how the lifeCycle of the `fragment` work. In the code posted below, in the line

```
int rotation = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
```

is using `getActivity()` optimal here? if yes, why my app crashes when added it? Please see the `Logcat` out put posted below.

***Java_Code***

```
public class Fragment02 extends Fragment {

private final String TAG = Fragment02.class.getName();
private StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder("");

OnClickListener btn_00_Listener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int rotation = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

        Toast mToast;

        switch(rotation) {

        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            mToast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.portrait, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            mToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 10, 0);
            mToast.show();
            Log.i(TAG, "PORTRAIT");
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            mToast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.landscape, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            mToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 10, 0);
            mToast.show();
            Log.i(TAG, "LANDSCAPE");
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            mToast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.reverse_portrait, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            mToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 10, 0);
            mToast.show();
            Log.i(TAG, "REVERSE_PORTRAIT");
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            mToast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.reverse_landscape, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            mToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 10, 0);
            mToast.show();
            Log.i(TAG, "REVERSE_LANDSCAPE");
            break;

        default:
            Log.i(TAG, "REVERSE_PORTRAIT");
        }// end switch

    }
};

public void onAttach(android.app.Activity activity) {
    strBuilder.append("@onAttached()./n");
    Log.i(TAG, ""+strBuilder);
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    strBuilder.append("@onCreate()./n");
    Log.i(TAG, ""+strBuilder);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    strBuilder.append("@onCreateView()./n");
    Log.i(TAG, ""+strBuilder);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_screen_orientation_change, container, false);
    Button btn_00 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_00);
    btn_00.setOnClickListener(btn_00_Listener);
    return v;
}
```

***LogCat***

```
  10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627): Process: com.example.viewpagerwithactiontabstest00, PID: 31627
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627): android.support.v4.app.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment Fragment02{4291abe8 #1 id=0x7f080000 android:switcher:2131230720:1} did not call through to super.onAttach()
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17350)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17350)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:382)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17350)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2505)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17350)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2175)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1316)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1513)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1200)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6388)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
10-25 12:52:19.550: E/AndroidRuntime(31627):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `onAttach()` in code is missing a `super.anAttach()` call.

Comment: @S.D. thank you for your answer. but i have two question for you please: 1- how did you know from the `logcat` that the problem is about `onAttach`? 2-why when I auto generated `onAttch` eclipse did not include the `super` method and an instance of the activit is passed to it, which causes the app not to work. but after adding the `super` method and passed a bundl, it works

Comment: @S.D. 1onAttach` know looks like this `public void onAttach(Activity savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  super.onAttach(savedInstanceState);
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You weren't calling the super's `onAttach` method that's why the error was being thrown.
2. You forgot the `@Override` annotation for the `onAttach` method.
3. Third, you should just implement the clickListener instead of creating it as a member object.

Try this:

```
public class Fragment02 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final String TAG = "Fragment02";

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        Log.i(TAG, "@onAttach");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "@onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "@onCreateView");
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_screen_orientation_change, container, false);
        Button btn_00 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_00);
        btn_00.setOnClickListener(this);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int rotation = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

        Toast mToast;

        switch(rotation) {

            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                mToast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.portrait, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                mToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 10, 0);
                mToast.show();
                Log.i(TAG, "PORTRAIT");
                break;

            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                mToast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.landscape, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                mToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 10, 0);
                mToast.show();
                Log.i(TAG, "LANDSCAPE");
                break;

            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                mToast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.reverse_portrait, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                mToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 10, 0);
                mToast.show();
                Log.i(TAG, "REVERSE_PORTRAIT");
                break;

            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                mToast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.reverse_landscape, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                mToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 10, 0);
                mToast.show();
                Log.i(TAG, "REVERSE_LANDSCAPE");
                break;

            default:
                Log.i(TAG, "REVERSE_PORTRAIT");
        }// end switch
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. please let me know why the `onattach` callback should be as you stated, because mine now is as follows and it works `public void onAttach(Activity savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  super.onAttach(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: another question please, what is the difference between implementing the onclicklistener and creating it as a member?

Comment: @LetsAmrIt [@Override](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) is a good practice. It warns you if the super doesn't have such a method. Implementing makes the code look cleaner. You could alternatively create a listener as an anonymouse class inside onCreateView and then use it. Don't know why you would instantiate it like you had in your code.

Comment: kindly, would you please have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562013/isnt-each-fragment-has-its-own-lifecycle-why-there-are-duplicate-of-lifecylce               and upvote my question if you do not minde